# Periodic system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

We have the following system:

$\dot{x}=x-y-x(x^2+y^2)$

$\dot{y}=y+x-y(x^2+y^2)$

1. Determine the equilibrium points
2. Show that this system has a periodic solution. Use the following substitution $x=r\cos(\phi), y=r\sin(\phi)$.
3. Give the explicit solution for this system. Also determine the period of this solution.

I found the following equilibrium point: $(x,y)=(0,0)$. I believe this is the only one.
I don't know how to use this substitution to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x^2+y^2=r^2$$

Differentiating this gives you: 
$$2xx'+2yy'=2rr'$$

Now you substitute $x'$ and $y'$:

$$x(x-y-x(x^2+y^2))+y(y+x-y(x^2+y^2))=rr'$$

This gives us:

$$x^2-xy-x^2(x^2+y^2)+y^2+xy-y^2(x^2+y^2)=rr'$$

$$x^2-xy-x^2r^2+y^2+xy-y^2r^2=rr'$$

$$x^2-r^2(x^2+y^2)+y^2=rr'$$

$$r^2-r^4=rr'$$

$$r-r^3=r'$$

To determine angle use:

$$\dfrac{r \sin \theta}{r \cos \theta} = \tan \theta = \dfrac{y}{x}$$

Using the quotient rule gives us:

$$\theta' = \dfrac{x y' - y x'}{r^2}=\dfrac{xy-y^2-xy(x^2+y^2)-xy-x^2+xy(x^2+y^2)}{r^2}$$

$$\theta'=-1$$

$$r'=r-r^3=r(1-r)(1+r)$$

check:

[Polar coordinates differential equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541889/polar-coordinates-differential-equation)

$$\dfrac{r \sin \theta}{r \cos \theta} = \tan \theta = \dfrac{y}{x}$$

$$ \tan \theta = \dfrac{y}{x} \rightarrow \theta=arctan\frac{y}{x} $$
Using the quotient rule gives us:

$$\theta' = arctan(\frac{y}{x})=\dfrac{(\frac{y}{x})'}{1+(\frac{y}{x})^2} =\dfrac{x y' - y x'}{r^2}$$

Comment: Can you explain how you get an expression for $\theta '$?