# Solve the dynamical system in polar coordinates

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I have the system (it is time dependent, this is a simplified notation):
\begin{cases} x' = x - y - x^3 \\ y' = x + y - y^3 \\ \end{cases}

I can't seem to solve it for r, $\theta$. (The change of variables is: $x = r\cos \theta$ and $y = r\sin \theta$, I used the fact that $x^2 + y^2 = r^2 $ and then $rr' = xx' + yy'$, but I stumble it the middle of the calculation). All feedback is welcomed.

Edit: Here are my calculations:
$$rr' = xx' + yy' \Leftrightarrow rr' = x(x-y-x^3) + y(x+y-y^3)$$
$$\Leftrightarrow rr' = r^2 - (x^4 + 2x^2y^2 + y^4) + 2x^2y^2 $$

$$\Leftrightarrow rr' = r^2 - r^4 + r^4(\cos^2 \theta \sin^2 \theta).$$
I was actually wondering whether it was possible to solve for $r$ without having $\theta$ in the result.

Comment: Do you get $r' = -\dfrac{1}{4} r \left(r^2 \cos (4 t)+3 r^2-4\right)$? Do you know how to find $\theta'$?

Comment: I'd use $\theta = \arctan \frac{y}{x}$. And no, may you elaborate on your calculations?

Comment: You have $r r' = x x' + y y'$. Substitute and simplify and solve for $r'$. Please note, I changed $\theta$ to $t$ above. You might want to review: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541889/polar-coordinates-differential-equation

Comment: "I stumble it the middle of the calculation" Please show the calculation.

Comment: There you go.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Were you able to converge?